# trying get post body in wordpress but not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to wordpress and am trying to get post body.
am doing it like this
the theme that am using is classiad
they getiing there post meta like this

```
$plan_featured_ads = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured_ads', true);
```

using this same approach am not getting post body

```
$post_content = get_post_field($post->ID, 'post_content');
```

this returns nothing, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've already got an instance of `WP_Post` in `$post`, so to access the `post_content` you can do the following:

```
// If you need an un-filtered version of the post:
$post->post_content;

// If you need a filtered version of the post for displaying on screen:
apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```